# Bottom messing up

Tags: troubleshooting

[image]

We are having an issue where the bottom of every print is not sticking to the bed but the brim is great but when it starts the print it start in the corner and the filament does not lay flat.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Could you add a photo while printing half-way the first layer? (So that we can see the brim and part of the layer) What print speeds, temperatures for hotend and bed and what print speeds are you using?

Comment: What's your actual question? How this problem is classified? What the cause of it is? How it can be fixed? Try to formulate an actual question in the title.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that's a photo of the bottom of a print?

To my eyes that looks like the filament is being squished into the bed way too much, which may result in it being dragged along with the nozzle, which causes it to curl up behind the nozzle a detach.

Try increasing your Z-offset, so the nozzle is slightly **higher** than it is now.

... it also looks like the filament is not sticking to itself at all. What type of filament is that, what print settings did you use, and what sort of bed surface do you use (PEI? Is it heated?)? Make sure the bed is clean - I recommend using soap and water to clean it like you would your hands, and **then** isopropyl alcohol to remove any oils your fingers (or moisturiser in the soap) may have left.

The usual steps for poor bed adhesion are:

- Clean the bed properly
- Slow down the print
- Increase the temperature of the bed (~60 °C for PLA is usual)

If none of that worked, you can try putting down a layer of gluestick (like you used as a child, i.e. PVA glue). It is water soluble, so you can just wash it off the part and bed when you are done.

You can also buy specialist glues like [3Dlac](https://www.3dlac.com/) if nothing else seems to work.